# specify range request length for Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, networking, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm making a small media server for personal use and I'm trying to use range requests because it'll be sending movies/tv shows that type of stuff. I have it use 8mb chunk sizes, which seems fine performance wise. However, Firefox is asking for the entire file. I've seen that when it asks for bytes "0-" you're supposed to give the entire thing, but that kind of defeats the purpose, doesn't it? I have control over the client and server side (which is running a python socket so I can control packet by packet what's going on) but I don't see anything anywhere on how to specify what size of video to request, such that it asks for 0-8388608.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers will for plain mp4 or similar files ask for the entire file and cache aggressively. Now, if you actively seek in the client, they tend to then close the connection and ask for the rest using a byte offset.

If you are trying to get it to only ask for chunks or segments at the time, you will need to move to proper adaptive streaming such as HLS or MPEG-DASH. Of those standards, HLS is likely the most simple to implement, but both will require at the very least, creation of a manifest file.

There is no way to control this behaviour in javascript or otherwise when simply giving the browser a plain .mp4 or similar file.

Comment: It looks like since I'll eventually want this as cross platform as possible, and HLS is reportedly not supported by Android, I'll need to do DASH. Which looks like it's going to be a pain to learn on my own. Thank you for letting me know though.

Comment: @Neywiny often enough i find Android supports HLS fine. It depends a little on the device and the generation. If you are deploying an app with ExoPlayer though, i believe it is almost 100% though.

Comment: Okay thanks. I guess the reference I was looking at was outdated. I'll have to give HLS a closer look then.